# Question on convex sets and their sums

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

I was recently presented with this question in convex geometry, which I cannot really solve and need help on, which is as follows:

> Assume that $ A,B \subset R^n $ are closed convex sets, and C is a bounded
>
> subset of $ R^n $ such that $ A + C = B + C $. We are to show that $ A = B $

The problem here is I have no real idea how to solve it. I know Cartheodory's theorem and basic convex geometry like support and separation but I cannot go further, I cannot seem to be able to solve it. Help appreciated thanks

Comment: Note that without the restriction that $C $ is bounded, this would not hold.  So keep in mind we will have to use the boundedness of $C $ somewhere in the proof.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you my professor already said that all conditions are necessary and there are no extras here. Could you please assist further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proceed by contradiction, assuming that $A\neq B$. Without loss of generality, suppose $a\in A$ but $a\notin B$. Separate $a$ from $B$ by a hyperplane, so you have a linear inequality $l(x)\leq q$ satisfied by all points in $B$ but not by $a$.  Let $s$ be the supremum of the values of $l(x)$ for $x\in C$.  (This is where I use that $C$ is bounded.) Choose some $c\in C$ such that $s-l(c)<l(a)-q$.  Then $l(a+c)$ is larger than $q+s$ and is therefore larger than $l(b+c')$ for all $b\in B$ and $c'\in C$.  Therefore $a+c\notin B+C$, contradiction the assumption that $A+C=B+C$.